Can MANCOVA be applied for the following parallel factorial trials?
Good morning everyone, I have a question about the validity of MANCOVA for a project. I have a factorial experiment to optimize removal efficiency "Y", considering two factors (velocity "A" with 2 levels and dose "B" with 3 levels) and a covariate water quality"M". Due to the availability of two identical pilots, I can run the experiment in pairs/parallel, where in each run each pilot has different speed levels "A" but I have the limitation (for operational reasons) that only both pilots can share the same dose level "B". In other words, i can do 2 runs at once, that covers all the levels of the factor A, but only allows changing the dose level "B" to the same level for both pilots. Supposedly, this design violates the principle of complete randomization and independence in the variable "B". I would like to know if the MANCOVA method is still valid? or what correction or other methods should I consider for this particular case? i am still a novice in DOE.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
